# Ruby on Rails 3: Sign-In With devise and cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails application which uses Device and Cancan for authentication. When I tried to sign in through my Rails Web view it works fine, but when I tried in Rest client I am getting an error. Is there any token I need to pass while signing in?

Sign in details..

```
http://localhost:3001/users/sign_in

{

  "username"      : "abcd",
  "password"      : "abcd"

}
```

In Rails Web View

```
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V", "authenticity_token"=>"A6GbMQxnQO6ELz/QM3yRIDYM5xfFi
Whn6nTLodfghYtU=", "user"=>{"username"=>"admin", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "comm
it"=>"Sign in"}
```

There is no other parameters other than user credentials are posted through Web view.

How to solve this through REST CLIENT?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I accept the question, i added "before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:create, :sign_in]" But it didn't help. => "{"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}"

Comment: Not sure about this one but Rails automatically adds hidden inputs like **authenticity_token** so this may prevent your request to work.

Comment: even if we are not using devise rails by default pass authenticity_token.Its part of rails security.

Comment: i found the way to sign-in...Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the link https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-flow

Before that you need to register your application to get the Client_id and secret_id

in Device Registration path is : `http://localhost:3000/oauth/applications/new`

Once You get the access tocken you can access the resources by passing the access tocken as query string along with resource URL

Eg : `http://localhost:3000/users?access_token=<!----access_token----!>`